# Intersperse and the hidden function prependToAll

Tags: haskell

There are two possibilities to intersperse a separator in a list:

- `[x1, sep, x2, sep, .. xn]`
- `[sep, x1, sep, x2, .. sep, xn]`

Using the function "intersperse" in Data.List:

```
λ> intersperse 0 [1..5]
[1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5] 
λ> 0 : intersperse 0 [1..5]
[0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5]
```

However the second case can be simplified using the hidden (not exported) function "prependToAll":

```
λ> prependToAll 0 [1..5]
[0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5]
```

Why, in Data.List library, **intersperse** is exported whereas the dual **prependToAll** is not?

Comment: You can simplify `prependToAll` as `prependToAll x = (x :) . intersperse x`, which is also pretty simple.

Comment: @AntalS-Z: from Data.Library: intersperse sep (x:xs)  = x : prependToAll sep xs
Hence: prependToAll' sep (x:xs) = sep : x : prependToAll sep xs. It seems to me a little redundant.

Comment: @AntalS-Z I'm not so sure. I would bet `prependToAll x [] = []`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Oops, you're right.

Comment: You can *correctly* simplify it as `prependToAll = (=<<) . (. return) . (:)`. :-D

Comment: Or I suppose `prependToAll = (=<<) . (. (: [])) . (:)` is shorter and has the distinct advantage of having no letters.

Comment: The premise of your question is not quite right, since intersperse produces just `[x1, sep, x2, sep, .. xn]` with no leading or trailing `sep`. Maybe that by itself clarifies the issue.

Comment: @ReidBarton Fixed the example. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

From [the comment on `prependToAll` in the `Data.List` source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#prependToAll):

```
 ...
 -- Not exported:
 -- We want to make every element in the 'intersperse'd list available
 -- as soon as possible to avoid space leaks. Experiments suggested that
 -- a separate top-level helper is more efficient than a local worker.
 ...
```

Comment: So, if I need a list separator in the first place I have to reimplement prependToAll, exactly as it is in Data.List library, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani If you can make a solid case for exposing `prependToAll`, feel free to do so. The [wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Library_submissions) has some guidelines for writing a good proposal to the libraries mailing list (see especially the "Guide to proposers" section). Fair warning: "because it would be convenient for me at this moment" is probably not sufficient justification.

Comment: I wonder if that comment is still true with newer GHCs. It's hard to imagine why a _closed_ local worker function would be any slower than its top-level equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`prependToAll` is not such a clear name. I would have guessed that

```
prependToAll x = map (x :)
```

so that `prependToAll :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`.

It's easier to just write the function you want inline as a `concatMap` or a `foldr` than it is to come up with a good name for it.

Comment: Does that require explanation? The purpose of `prependToAll` is as an auxiliary definition for `intersperse`, which is more commonly useful and less trivial. One doesn't normally export such auxiliary definitions "by default".

Comment: Then why isn't it defined in a `where` clause after `intersperse`?

Comment: That particular question is addressed by kaz's answer.

Comment: Not really. If `prependToAll` was more non-trivial and easier to name clearly, then it might have been worth exporting on its own merits. There's lots of ways to slice up this question.